# Angular 6: <img src="/src/assets/images/someimage.png"> is not showing up

Tags: angular, image

In my user.component.html

```
... 
  <div>
      <img class="user-image" src="src/assets/images/poolride-user.png">
  </div>
...
```

I searched that but didn't get the proper answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using .. to navigate to correct path.Don't type the address instead use the angular's auto complete feature to insert the path. Type .. and hit control + space and traverse using auto complete.

Comment: `<img class="user-image" src="assets/images/poolride-user.png">`

Comment: @Ahmed your approach to address this issue is accurate, actually my component is inside a module and the best way to find the path is to get the hint by using (Ctrl+Space)

Therefore in my case the path that worked for me is as under:

 <div>
          <img class="user-image" src="../../../assets/images/poolride-user.png">
 </div>

Thanks for saving my day !

Answer (score 1):

In your `angular.json` in `assets` section

```
projects=>ProjectName=>architect=>build=>options=>assets
```

Add the following string:

```
"src/assets"
```

Then :

```
<div>
      <img class="user-image" src="assets/images/poolride-user.png">
</div>
```

or use this :

```
 <img class="user-image" src="./assets/images/poolride-user.png">
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my component is inside another module and the best way to find the exact path is to get the hint by using **(Ctrl+Space)** - big thanks to Visual Studio. Therefore in my case the path that worked for me is as under:

...

```
<img class="user-image" src="../../../assets/images/user-img.png">
```

...

**Component path** : my-project/src/app/my-module/my-component

**Image path** : my-project/src/assets/images/user-img

Happy Coding :)